# How do you get the admin console on ark?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

How do you get the admin console in ark?

Comment: NGL, but why could you not google this?

Answer (score 0):

- On the PC you use tab.
- On console, in the pause screen press both bumpers and X and Y or triangle and square, depending on your controller.

Source:
https://ark.gamepedia.com/Console_Commands

Comment: @Dpeif Edited. Sorry I'm a PC gamer, not console :).